# Lottie animation with parrallax effect on page scroll

Tags: css, position, css-position, lottie

I am trying to create interactive lottie animation and I got it work by following [official guide](https://lottiefiles.com/interactivity). But having a problem, the animation is long and I need kind of parallax effect which will ideally start and end with the animation. I tried couple of css solutions, in particular `position: fixed` with custom `height` but the animation stops working using these properties.

**Sample Code with fixed position:** (no animation)

```html
<body style="height: 1000px;">

    <div id="MyContainerId" style="position: fixed;">
        <lottie-player id="firstLottie" src="https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_ug2jsixg.json" background="transparent" speed="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></lottie-player>
    </div>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity@latest/dist/lottie-interactivity.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        LottieInteractivity.create({
            mode: 'scroll',
            player: '#firstLottie',
            container: '#MyContainerId',
            actions: [{
                visibility: [0, 1],
                type: 'seek',
                frames: [0, 100],
            }, ],
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**Sample Code with sticky position:** (animates but hides from screen)

```html
<body style="height: 1000px;">

    <div id="MyContainerId" style="position: sticky;">
        <lottie-player id="firstLottie" src="https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_ug2jsixg.json" background="transparent" speed="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></lottie-player>
    </div>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity@latest/dist/lottie-interactivity.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        LottieInteractivity.create({
            mode: 'scroll',
            player: '#firstLottie',
            container: '#MyContainerId',
            actions: [{
                visibility: [0, 1],
                type: 'seek',
                frames: [0, 100],
            }, ],
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I guess, I am using wrong combination of css properties. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, just don't use the sticky div as container, create a new separated one and place it below the player. Then use a new div as wrapper for both elements.

Also, if you add a bottom div outside the wrapper, you can scroll up the player once the animation has finished.

```html
<body >
    <div>
        <div style="background-color:transparent; height:1px; position:sticky; top:0">
            <lottie-player 
                id="firstLottie" 
                src="https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_ug2jsixg.json" 
                background="transparent" 
                speed="1" 
                style="width:100%; height: auto;"
            ></lottie-player>
        </div>

        <div id="MyContainerId" style="height:300vh; background-color:transparent"></div>
    
    
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity@latest/dist/lottie-interactivity.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            LottieInteractivity.create({
                mode: 'scroll',
                player: '#firstLottie',
                container: '#MyContainerId',
                actions: [{
                    visibility: [0, 1],
                    type: 'seek',
                    frames: [0, 100],
                }, ],
            });
        </script>
    </div>

        <div style="height:200vh; background-color:wheat"></div>

    </body>
```